# Django ajax redirecting on form submission

Tags: python, jquery, ajax, django

I'm trying to return data with an ajax request on a form submission.  My goal was too use two views, one too handle the template loading and the other to handle the POST request from the form.  In the current state, the form is redirecting to the JSON that is in the callback.  That makes sense as it's for the form action url is pointing, however, i want to just pass the data to the current page and not reload the page or be redirected to another page.

Here is the code:

user.html

```
<form action="{% url 'ajax-user-post' %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
   {% for user in users %}
  <input type="submit" name="name" value="{{ user }}">
{% endfor %}
```

views.py

```
def ajax_user(request):
  # get some data..

  if request.METHOD == 'POST':
    user = request.POST['user']
    user_data = User.objects.get(user=user)

    data = {'user_data': user_data}
    return JsonResponse(data)


def user(request):
  return render(request, 'user.html', context)
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^user/', user, name="user"),
url(r'^ajax/user/', ajax_user, name="ajax-user-post")
```

.js

```
$('form').on('submit', function(){
  var name = // the name of the user selected
  $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: 'ajax/user/',
        data: { 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': csrftoken, 'name': name, 'form': $form.serialize() },
        success:function(data) {
          // hide the current data
          console.log(data);
          displayUserData(data)
        }
  })
});
```

Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> i want to just pass the data to the current page and not reload the page or be redirected to another page.

That means you need to stop the form submission event with the [event.preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) call.

Hence, change this line from:

```
$('form').on('submit', function(){
```

to to following two:

```
$('form').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
```

Comment: well, the whole time i was thinking this was a django thing... should have seen this, thanks!!